# Вычислить среднее значение из нескольких чисел

Tags: java

Необходимо написать код для вычисления *среднего значения* из всех инпут-переменных

```java
public class MyCalculator {
    int input1 = 10;
    int input2 = 20;
    int input3 = 30;
    int input4 = 40;
    int input5 = 50;

    public float average() {
        // TODO: write java code to calculate the average for all input variable
        // вот здесь нужен код
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: То, что нужен код, это понятно, но вы вопрос забыли написать.

Comment: Программа на javascript 

Comment: Раз необходимо написать, то напишите.

Answer (score 1):

// Ответ был дан на пост [с тегом] и [заголовком содержащим keyword] - `javascript`

Нет вопроса, есть ответ

На, попей

```js
// Все импуты:
let input1 = 1;
let input2 = 4;
let input3 = 8;

const arr = [input1, input2, input3]; // складоваемс

let result = arr.reduce((r, a)=>(r+a)); // считаем сумм
result = result / arr.length; // делим сумм, для мстителей(average)

console.log(result); // не знаю что эта штука делает
```

Comment: Vadim: ответ неверный. Вопрос добавлен.

Comment: @user385173 ответ верный

Comment: @user385173 составь свой вопрос так, чтобы он заканчивался знаком вопроса (а лучше его сразу в гугл вбей) и потом уже поговорим (: